# How do I convert a string into a react component?

Tags: reactjs

```
function ConvertStringToComponent(componentString: string) {
        // parse(`<${componentString}></${componentString}>`)
        return React.createElement(componentString, {})
    }

    let listOfNavElements = [
        {
            path: "/",
            element: ConvertStringToComponent('HomePage'),
            name: "Home"
        },
        {
            path: '/architecture',
            element: <ArchitecturePage></ArchitecturePage>,
            name: "Architecture"
        },
        {
            path: '/About',
            element: <AboutPage></AboutPage>,
            name: "About"
        },
        {
            path: '/contact',
            element: <ContactPage></ContactPage>,
            name: "Contact"
        }
    ]

    return (
        <>
            <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div className="relative flex h-16 items-center justify-between">
                    <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center sm:items-stretch sm:justify-start">
                        <div className="flex flex-shrink-0 items-center"></div>
                        <div className="hidden sm:ml-6 sm:block">
                            <div className="flex space-x-4">
                                {listOfNavElements.map((page) => (
                                    <Link to={page.path} className={navClassNames}>{page.name}</Link>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <Routes>
                {listOfNavElements.map((page) => (
                    <Route path={page.path} element={page.element}></Route>
                ))}
            </Routes>
        </>
    )
```

```
function HomePage() {
    // TODO: dynamically generate the each tab on the navbar


    return (
        <>
            <h1>Homepage</h1>
        </>
    )
}

export default HomePage
```

I want to dynamically render my routes and links in this component which means that I will be saving the element: property as a string in the DB. I want to be able to convert the string

e.g. 'HomePage' -> `<Homepage></Homepage>` so that react knows that "/" = Homepage Component

When i tried using "return React.createElement(componentString, {})"

I get an error where the Tag is unrecognized in this browser If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.

I'm not too sure how to carry on from here...

Comment: Getting an error like "start its name with an uppercase letter." makes me think you weren't actually passing a valid component name.

Comment: I have updated the above code to include the HomePage component.

Answer (score 3):

Custom react components can't be passed as a string. Here's a link to the [createElement](https://react.dev/reference/react/createElement) documentation. A string can be used for any built-in html tag. While a custom component requires the function.

```
React.createElement(HomePage)
```

--

Technically you could service custom components as a string from an external source like a database. If those components were encoded in a way using only built-in tags. Of course, that would be a huge hassle.

I'd recommend doing some sort of remapping from the database value, to the component.

```
if (navString === "HomePage") return <HomePage />
...
```